# How to create formula that copies 15 rows and inserts below

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I am a newbie when it comes to formulae and macros in spreadsheets. I am creating a manager sheet for a tabletop gaming group, and during the game players may add additional characters to their character group.

For each player I have created a roster sheet which records key information of the characters in a player's band. I want to create a custom menu that will copy a blank version of the last character entry below the current last character, maintaining the formulae and data validation, but erasing it of entered values (so players do not need to clean it up to make it ready for a new character):

[image: Roster Screenshot]

Here, number 14 is a formula which adds to the previous fighter number; the drop down menus are data validation to sheets elsewhere in the doc, and Vlookups automatically insert information into the columns connected to those validations (so as to make the sheet useable for my players).

However if a player wished to add fighter 15 (or further), I would like to make it easier for them without having to do lots of copying and pasting.

I have seen formulae like the following, but not sure how to make it grab in this case the box of 14 rows and 31 columns that is required for a new character, nor how to clean the copied cells of entered data while preserving the data validation & vlookup formulae:

> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
>
> function onOpen() {
> var menu = [{name:"Add New Last Row", functionName:"addRow"}];
> ss.addMenu("AM FUNCTIONS", menu);
> }

> function addRow() {
> var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow();
> var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
> sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow,1);
> var formulas = range.getFormulas();
> var newRange = sh.getRange(lRow+1,1,1,lCol);
> newRange.setFormulas(formulas);
> }

I am not sure if this is the right way to approach this problem, and hope you can help.